# Unable to play media files from windows server

Tags: samba, media, 22.04

I have a problem to play any media files from my Windows server sharing folders. When I try it by opening (Nautilus or DoubleComm) it returns the error "SMB protocol source is required to play the file, but is not installed." and of course, "Find in ubuntu software" do not find anything.

I am not experienced user with Linux but I tried to search for any solutions on internet but without results.

Windows server is running the Windows server 2012 OS (SMB1). I have on local PC Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: SMBv1 support is being deprecated across a lot of modern OSes due to its insecurities. [Windows Server 2012 *does* support SMBv2 and SMBv3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3), so you may want to look at updating the protocol that's used 

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, you are right. But I do not have a problem with access files on server at all. I have a problem with playing music of video from that server. Browsing folders, opening pictures or other documents I can do without problems. Music or video file from the server I have to copy it first to local folder of Ubuntu station from which I can play it without issues.

Comment: I face the same issue even though my Samba server uses SMB2 and SMB3 but no SMB1.

Comment: Same problem here using SMB2 and SMB3.  This has broken after updating to Ubuntu 22.04.  Everything was working OK on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Same here.. Note this is using the userspace "fuse" mounts. I suspect that a proper fstat based mount will work just fine.